# python: pandas apply function: InvalidIndexError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply

I am using `apply` on my data frame `my_df` like below:

```
my_df['column_C'] = my_df.apply(lambda x : 'hello' if x['column_B'] is None else x['column_B'] )
```

I want:

```
  if x['column_B'] = None -> return 'hello'
  if x['column_B'] != None -> return x['column_B']
```

Then I got the following errors:

```
<ipython-input-31-aa087c9a635e> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 my_df['column_C'] = my_df.apply(lambda x : 'hello' if x['column_B'] is None else x['column_B'] )

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    599         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    600         try:
--> 601             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    602 
    603             if not is_scalar(result):

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   2187             # python 3
   2188             if is_scalar(key):  # pragma: no cover
-> 2189                 raise IndexError(key)
   2190             raise InvalidIndexError(key)
   2191 

IndexError: ('column_B', 'occurred at index column_A')
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong here?

Comment: why not: `my_df['column_C'] = my_df['column_C'].fillna('hello')`?

Comment: This is certainly a smarter approach thanks! Still curious about what was wrong in the apply function though ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply specifying `axis=1` to apply it to each row, not each column. See the documentation on [DataFrame.apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
axis : {0 or 'index', 1 or 'columns'}, default 0

* 0 or 'index': apply function to each column
* 1 or 'columns': apply function to each row
```

In your current call, it cannot find `x['column_B']` when it's really using a pd.Series that corresponds to `column_A`.

So if you use the following it will work.

```
my_df['column_C'] = my_df.apply(lambda x : 'hello' 
                                if x['column_B'] is None
                                else x['column_B'], axis=1)
```

Note: as pointed in the comment above, [DataFrame.fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) is more appropriate for this task.